# Fundamental theorem of calculus problem - trig functions

Tags: integration, derivatives

My problem is:

[image]

On the interval (0 , pi/2).

I know I need to split it in two integrals, but I don't know how.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: By partial fractions $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{1+x}\right)$. Does this help?

Comment: Not exactly, what I don't understand is how I'm supposed to split up the upper and lower limit (cos and sin). Can I choose any random number between (0 , pi/2)?

Answer (score 1):

You can just calculate the improper integral first:

$$
\int \frac{dx}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{dx}{1-x}}+\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{dx}{1+x}} = -\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-x|+\frac{1}{2}\ln|1+x|+C
$$

which holds for $|x|\not= 1$. Given that in the interval $(0,\pi /2)$, $\sin$ or $\cos$ are never $1$ or $-1$, you're safe. Then just finish it off:
$$
f(\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-\cos{\theta}|+\frac{1}{2}\ln|1+\cos{\theta}|+\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-\sin{\theta}|-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1+\sin{\theta}| = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{|(1+\cos\theta)(1-\sin\theta)|}{|(1-\cos\theta)(1+\sin\theta)|}}=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta}{(1-\cos\theta)^2(1+\sin\theta)^2}}
$$

I mean, I think it's done, but maybe you can find a nice factorization.

Answer (score 0):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

$\displaystyle f^{\prime}(\theta)=\frac{-\sin\theta}{1-\cos^{2}\theta}-\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos^{2}\theta}=-\csc\theta-\sec\theta$,

so $\displaystyle f(\theta)=-\left[\ln(\csc\theta-\cot\theta)+\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)\right]+C=-\left[\ln((\csc\theta-\cot\theta)(\sec\theta+\tan\theta))\right]+C$

$\displaystyle\;\;=-\ln((\csc\theta+1)(\sec\theta-1))+C=-\ln((\csc\theta+1)(\sec\theta-1))=\ln((\sec\theta+1)(\csc\theta-1))$

since $f(\frac{\pi}{4})=0\implies-\ln((\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}-1))+C=0\implies C=\ln1=0$